# Solutions of $\arctan x = 1 - x$. Proofs?

Tags: real-analysis

In this question, we examine the equation $\arctan x = 1 - x$. You may assume without proof that $\arctan x$ is continuous on $R$.

a) Prove that there is a solution to the equation in the interval $(0,1)$. [Hint: IVT]
b) Prove that there can't be a second solution in R. [Hint: Use a proof by contradiction using Rolle's Theorem]

Comment: $f(x)=\arctan{x}-1+x$

Comment: About the second point: Rolle's theorem is quite an overkill, since the function $x+\arctan x$ is trivially increasing over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

The function
$$ g(x)=x+\arctan x $$
is continuous and increasing over $\mathbb{R}$, hence $g(x)=1$ cannot hold in more than one point. Since $g(0)=0<1$ and $g(1)=1+\frac{\pi}{4}>1$ it holds for sure for some point of the interval $(0,1)$ by the IVT.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function
$$
f(x)=1-x-\arctan x
$$
so that your problem is equivalent to finding values of $x$ where $f(x)=0$.

As the hint proposes, we have $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=-\pi/4$, so by the IVT there is a point $x$ in $(0,1)$ where $f(x)=0$.

Since the second hint mentions Rolle's theorem, we can look at the derivative:
$$
f'(x)=-1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$
and it should be clear how to go on, by remembering what Rolle's theorem says.

Comment: You can not use Relle's Theorem here since it requires $f(0)=f(1)$. Instead you have to use the mean value theorem for continuous functions.

Comment: @xpaul *If* there are $a$ and $b$ with $a<b$ and $f(a)=0=f(b)$, then $f$ would satisfy the hypotheses of Rolle's theorem in the interval $[a,b]$. But…

Comment: it is still wrong since your $f(x)$ is monotonic and you can not get $f(a)=f(b)$ unless $a=b$.

Comment: @xpaul No, it's *right*: assuming the existence of $a$ and $b$ would contradict the fact that $f'(x)<0$. I'd do it in the same way as you, but I just wanted to use the hint for the OP's benefit.